# Replace number with string in table based on another table mysql

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have a problem related to a front end I develop for a MySQL database. I have two tables, table 1 (T1) consists of one column with integers, table 2 (T2) consists of one col with integers and a corresponding col with strings. T1 and T2 are not of the same length.

T1 look like this:

```
num_t1
1
4
6
1
5
3
```

T2 look like this:

```
num_t2| string_t2
1     | s1
2     | s2
3     | s3
4     | s4
5     | s5
```

What I would like is to SELECT T1, but instead of getting the integers, I want a column with the strings from T2 where num_t1 and num_t2 are equal. Makes sense?

So, if I say

```
SELECT * FROM T1
```

instead of just num_t1, I want

```
s1
s4

s1
s5
s3
```

What is the code requiered to do so? Now I have a static fix like this

```
SELECT * FROM T1
CASE WHEN num_t1 = 1 THEN 's1'
     WHEN num_t1 = 2 THEN 's1'
     so on...
     ELSE 'Not available'
END AS num_t1_string
```

Is there a more dynamic way? So I dont need to modify the query every time i change the integers or string in T1 and T2.

Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

EDIT: The first question is now solved with the code inside brackets:

```
SELECT num_id
(SELECT T2.string_t2
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2
ON T1.num_t1 = T2.num_t2
ORDER BY T1.num_t1) AS string_t1
FROM T1
```

However, when I try to subquery this I get error 1242. Subquery returns more than one row. How can I solve this?

Comment: you can use join query for this...

Comment: Thank you, but I am not very familiar with the JOIN query, do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i said you can use join query like

```
select T1.num_t1,T2.string_t2 from T1 left join T2 on T1.num_t1=T2.num_t2
```

I have used right join here to get complete data of table T1

If you require complete documentation, you can refer to this link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Please alsp have a quick look at my edit to the question

Comment: yes it is correct as you are using a subquery as column so it should return one row only but it's returning multiple rows so it's giving error...

Comment: Ok, I guess that makes sense when I think about it, but how can I then add the subquery as a column to my table?

Comment: if you wanna to retrieve a unique value based on your condition provided as, subquery will not work for multiple values like in your case but you can do one thing i.e.

`select T1.num_t1 as num_id,(select string_t2 from T2 where num_t2=T1.num_t1) as string_t1 from T1`